# Regex to remove . and - in string using shell script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a string  `com.xyx.it.abc.sweta-test-parameter`
I need to convert it to `com/xyz/it/abc/swetatestparameter`

How can I achieve the output using Regex?

I need to replace . with / and remove - from string
Below is the attempt I tried:

```
Package_Name="com.xyx.it.abc.sweta-test-parameter"
Package=${Package_Name//-//}
```

The output is :

```
com/xyx/it/abc/sweta-test-parameter
```

Can someone please help?

Appreciate all your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: added the attempt

Comment: Using `sed`: `sed 's/-//g; s~\.~/~g' <<< "$Package_Name"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I assign the above solution to a variable?

Comment: Read about command substitution

Comment: Thanks so much, However, I'm curious to know how do you come up with such a regular expression? Is there any trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, `sed` will do the job. Please try replacing `Package=${Package_Name//-//}` with

```
Package=$(sed 's/\./\//g; s/-//g' <<< "$Package_Name")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly in bash, but it takes two steps:

```
Package_Name="com.xyx.it.abc.sweta-test-parameter"

Package=${Package_Name//.//}    # Replace each "." with "/"
Package=${Package//-/}          # Replace each "-" with "" (i.e. delete them)

echo "$Package"                 # Prints "com/xyx/it/abc/swetatestparameter"
```

Note that this does not use regular expressions. The substitution mechanism supports glob patterns (filename-style wildcards), but this doesn't even use that, just plain strings.

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon for your answer!